# How do I replace text that is already set in a richtextbox by using another radio button?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I click on one radio button, it sets the text in my richtextbox. If I click on another one, it'll do nothing. Is it possible to replace the text with another radio button?

```C#
private void M_buttonComment_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (M_buttonComment.Checked) //If checked == true
    {
        // Set the text to be "Comment" //
        M_TitleTextBox.Text = "Comment - ";                        
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty unclear what the problem is.  Use the debugger to step through your code when it runs.

Comment: Just assign a similar event to the other radio button

Comment: youve fallen into a common radiobutton trap. M_button is one right? theres more.. youve not checked which radio button is checked.

Comment: @BugFinder M_button is a radio button. I tried checking this one, but if I do this with a different one, it won't do the same event. I don't know why.

Comment: It's because you added the event to only that button.

Comment: Did you subscribe to the event or did you just copy this code?

Comment: your event only checks if M_buttonComment is checked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the same `CheckChanged` event for both the radio buttons.

Set this property for **both** radio buttons. (Name the method whatever you want, but make sure the name of the method is the same in the code.)

[image: Picture]

Then in your code:

```
private void SomeCustomEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radBtnOne.Checked) //If checked == true
    {
        M_TitleTextBox.Text = "From radio button one";                        
    }
    else if(radBtnTwo.Checked)
    {
        M_TitleTextBox.Text = "From radio button two";
    }
}
```

Notice that the same thing is happening if either radio button is checked in my example. If you don't care which radio button was checked and just want to do the same thing regardless then the following would work. `sender` in this case would be the radio button clicked.

But you could also figure out which radio button was clicked by looking at their `.Name` property.

```
private void SomeCustomEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
    if (rb.Checked) { // From either radio button
        M_TitleTextBox.Text = "A radio button was clicked.";
        if(rb.Name = "radBtnOne") // To check which one was checked.
        {
            // Now we know which radio button was clicked. Same process for the second
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the Text property as a key.  Use the control's name for that.

Comment: @Jimenemex I tried this same event with other radio buttons, but it wouldn't work. Your answer seems to work perfectly.